# Kinect camera's angle to the floor

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

Is there anyway to determine the angle of the Kinect v2 sensor with respect to the floor? Possibly using the XYZW coordinates of FloorClipPlane?

Comment: did you had a look on [this](https://www.gittprogram.com/question/1140684_floor-plane-detection.html) or [that](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/594cf9ed-3fa6-4700-872c-68054cac5bf0/angle-of-kinect-device-and-effect-on-xyz-positional-data?forum=kinectv2sdk) may be it can help

Comment: Yes, the second link i.e (that) is ambiguous. It gives me numbers with the range of 0.99 to 0.95 no matter how much I tilt the camera.

Comment: all 3 angles give these values in this range?

Comment: I used this. and tested 45 as well as 90 degrees. cameraAngleRadians= Math.Atan(floorClipPlane.Z / floorClipPlane.Y); 
            var cosCameraAngle = Math.Cos(cameraAngleRadians);